# ld problem - rpl_malloc (cross compiling ARM)

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors, compilation, arm

I have tried at compiling the tool **shc**. My system is amd64 and i want to compile it for arm architecture. I set it like this:

```
CC=arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc ./configure --host=arm
```

and when try **make**, appear this error (problem in **ld**, but i didn't understand how to fix it):

```
Making all in src
make[1]: ingresso nella directory "/shc/src"
arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc  -g -O2   -o shc shc.o  
shc.o: nella funzione "eval_shell":
/shc/src/shc.c:1010: reference not defined "rpl_malloc"
shc.o: in the function "make":
/shc/src/shc.c:1304: reference not defined at "rpl_realloc"
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:326: set di istruzioni per l'obiettivo "shc" non riuscito
make[1]: *** [shc] Error 1
Makefile:414: set of istructions for "all-recursive" 
make: *** [all-recursive] Errore 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit `configure.ac` and comment out `AC_FUNC_MALLOC` and `AC_FUNC_REALLOC` if present.