# Cross-compiling PTPD2 for a 64-bit ARM A-53 under Ubuntu for x64

Tags: gcc, embedded-linux, cross-compiling

I am attempting to cross-compile the PTPD project for 64-bit ARM (https://github.com/ptpd/ptpd). I have installed the aarch64 compilers and I can see the 64-bit ARM gcc compiler under /usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc. My host is Ubuntu 20.04 LTS for X64.

Having cloned the project, I am struggling to set the correct ./configure options. I've tried various options like:

```
./configure --target=aarch64-linux-gnu
```

But configure just seems to ignore the instruction to build for a different target platform

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Seem like the ./configure command needs to be:

```
./configure --host=aarch64-linux-gnu CC=/usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc
```

I also had to look at this Stackoverflow: [ld problem - rpl_malloc (cross compiling ARM)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67116092/ld-problem-rpl-malloc-cross-compiling-arm)
To solve the issue with the rpl_malloc symbol being missing during link time